# How to make an object accessible within its class, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, oop, subclass

In this class how can I have `fig` object with its own relevant properties available in its class, for example in `my_function`;

```
classdef Test
    properties
        a
        b
    end

    methods
        function obj = Test(a, b)
            obj.a = a;
            obj.b = b;
        end  
        function [] = my_function(obj)
            fig.Name   %%% here fig object is needed
            disp('done!')
        end  
        function [fig] = my_figure(obj) 
            fig = figure();
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `fig` as a property of your class and then from within `my_function`, you'll be able to access the `fig` property of the current instance. As a side note, if you'd like to be able to pass your class instance around by reference, you'll want to subclass MATLAB's `handle` class:

```
classdef Test < handle
    properties
        fig         % Setup a property to hold the handle to the figure
        a
        b  
    end

    methods
        function obj = Test(a, b)
            obj.a = a;
            obj.b = b;
        end  

        function [] = my_function(obj)
            % Access and modify the figure handle as needed
            obj.fig.Name = 'Name';
            disp('done!')
        end  

        function [fig] = my_figure(obj) 
            fig = figure();

            % Store the handle in the "fig" property of the class
            obj.fig = fig;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Suever, actually I did it but it doesn't return properties of `fig` object, maybe `Name` is not a good example, if you try with `obj.fig.CurrentPoint` there is no return, or I'm somewhere wrong?

Comment: @Hamidreza What do you mean by "there is no return"? Are you calling `my_figure` first to actually create the figure?

Comment: Yes, I do. I meant that, to get the own property of `figure` object, for example `obj.fig.CurrentPoint` - which should return the mouse cursor point on the figure - this is not working.

Comment: If you test it, you can't set the name of the figure in this way, because it is a figure property not a property of class `Test`.
This is my problem actually.

Comment: @Hamidreza What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: And did you subclass `handle` like I mentioned?

Comment: 2016a, with an academic license.

Comment: @Hamidreza Works fine for me. Please be sure to copy/paste what I have above *exactly* including the subclass of `handle`